# Getting found nil when "presentViewController" because of UIInterfaceOrientationMask

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, uiinterfaceorientation, guard

By solving the last big problem in my app I cause another, maybe bigger problem. My app is a portrait only, but I wanted to make it possible to watch videos in landscape. To do so I added this method to AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    guard let vc = (window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController) else {
        return .Portrait
    }

    if (vc.isKindOfClass(NSClassFromString("AVFullScreenViewController")!)) {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    }

    return .Portrait
}
```

Works perfectly well. But now, if I presenting an alert or click on some share buttons (open `configureMailComposeViewController() or UIActivityViewController()`) my app crashing.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2016-09-16 09:51:43.665772 App[1788:535789] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I don't understand that issue, shouldn't that guard protecting me from that issue and return .Portrait?
If I delete the method or just returning .Portrait everything works again with the ecxeption of landscape watching videos.

Please don't suggest to make my app excepting Landscape orientation to and disable it for every controller. I tried that, not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AVFullScreenViewController` when this viewcontroller pop or dismiss set interface orientation to portrait for your `window` or `statusbar`. you can manage it in `viewWillDisappear` of `AVFullScreenViewController`.

Comment: Yeah, but that controller ist not mine. iOS calls them automatically by presenting a video from webview (youtube). Or is there a way to work with extensions or so? Not jet familiar with that feature

Comment: How can I reach that `AVFullScreenViewController` ?